# Mis red local de la nada me está negando el acceso - Linux

Tags: linux, debian, redes, linux-mint

Sucede que comparto ficheros en una red local con nfs y a su vez monto un par de servidores de desarrollo para poder acceder a ellos desde la misma red local, ambos tienen la ip estatica, al menos localmente. El día de hoy me levanté con la sorpresa de lo siguiente:

Al intentar montar NFS me tira Timeout, al intentar acceder a los servidores montados el servidor rechaza la conexión.
Al hacer ping me arroja `"Destination Host Unreachable", rpcinfo` me tira `RPC: Remote system error - No route to host`, tengo el servidor montado en debian y el cliente accede a el desde linux mint ha estado funcionando perfectamente dias atras y desconozco por completo que puedo hacer para solucionar el problema.. Estuve buscando por internet durante un par de horas y probando un par de soluciones pero me topé con que usualmente esta situación suele pasar en situaciones muy especificas por lo que decidí hacer mi propia pregunta...

dejo una captura con los puertos que estoy utilizando localmente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1):

En base a lo que comentas, revisa todas las conexiones que tienes, o que ha cambiado desde la última vez (cuando funcionaba) hasta ahora.

Piensa en componentes como firewall y demás que puedan estar bloqueando las peticiones.

Comprueba que la ip no ha cambiado y sigue siendo la misma, aunque si tú mismo la estableciste de manera estática sería raro que cambiase, o si tienes restricciones para acceso a los servidores, si la ip cliente ha cambiado.

Comment: En este caso conservan las ip que yo le había dejado, intenté cambiarlas ambas, reinstalar nfs y no funcionó, en este caso como el servidor solo se usa localmente mi instalación de debian no tiene ningún firewall.. para detallar un poco más la pregunta dejé una captura con los puertos que estoy ocupando localmente

Comment: Tambien pruebe que el cable esté enchufado y funcioné el switch.